# wait() function in c

Tags: c, function, process, wait

I have two process. Their names are parent and child process. I want parent process wait child process without wait() function. How can I do this?

My code is here.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
intmain(int argc, char *argv[]) {
printf("hello world (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
int rc = fork();   if (rc < 0) { // fork failed; exit
    fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
    exit(1);
} else if (rc == 0) {      // child (new process)
    printf("hello, I am child (pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
} else {       // parent goes down this path (original process)

    printf("hello, I am parent of %d (wc:%d) (pid:%d)\n", rc, wc, (int) getpid());
}
return 0; }
```

Comment: Another 'I want to drive a nail but don't want to use a hammer'.

Comment: I wonder it. Is it possible?

Comment: Presumably you don't want to use waitpid() either? It's certainly possible, see the answer given below. But unless you have a good reason for wanting to do this, there is no point in not using some variant of wait().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You could write a loop that keeps checking if the child is running. You can use `kill` function to check if a process is alive.</strike> (This won't work, you can send a signal to a zombie process)

You could define a signal handler for SIGCHLD that sets a variable, and check that variable in a loop.

If you don't call some form of `wait` the child will become a zombie process though.